# How do I deploy Google colab (Jyputer NoteBook) on the Google Cloud to run automatically?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I got a Python script that I would like it to be run automatically every day at certain timing on my Google colab.

How do I get to run it on Google Cloud, or is there any other ways to run the file without downloading it as pyfile ? Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you asked two questions: one about running a script automatically, and one about running a script on Google Colab in general. I'm not sure that automatically running a script is supported yet, but to run any ipynb in Colab, you should be able to go to https://colab.research.google.com and open the file from your Google Drive or GitHub.

Comment: i see, yes my questions is how do i deploy the colab notebook to run it automatically ?  i try to search online but couldnt find much

Comment: Yes, I believe this is a feature that they're considering adding. I know you can do it on Google Cloud Platform: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/how-to-schedule-a-recurring-python-script-on-gcp

Comment: What particular constrictions do you have? Do you need to run it on Google Colab? Do you want to mantain the notebook format without changing to pure .py? Does the solution proposed by @rchurt work for you?